# How do I reload config in other instances of emacs?

Tags: init-file, server, config

Say, I changed `~/.emacs`, but I have another instances of `emacs` running. I believe unless I do something, they might change the config (because they have a stale notion of its contents), which in turn will result in losing the changes above. I can think of the following cases where `emacs` changes settings on its own:

- installing packages
- "easy" customization (`M-x customize`)
- adding/removing agenda files (`C-c [`, `C-c ]`)

How do I make it so that no changes is lost?

I don't want to use `emacs` server, since that supposedly means I have one frame (okay, not necessarily), one buffer list, and probably more. Or is this generally the best way to go about it after all?

Comment: you can do `M-x load-file` `~/.emacs` .

Comment: @djangoliv Will that make `emacs` aware that the config has changed, and if it were to change the config it should use the new (current) version?

Comment: Emacs will simply reload the configuration as if it were restarting.

Comment: For clarity, that doesn't mean that any kind of 'reset' takes place.  `load-file` will read and evaluate all of the code in the specified file, and that will happen "over the top" of whatever the current state was.  The result depends on what kind code you've actually written or changed in your init file.  (For example if you'd changed the default value of an existing `defvar` then evaluating that won't have an effect.  If you'd changed the value used in a `setq` then it would have an effect.)

Comment: You can also evaluate individual changes at run time.  https://masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs is a good overview of the facilities.

Comment: @phils About `load-file`, thought as much. But the question is not about bringing `emacs` to a certain state. It's about avoiding losing changes to the config file. Some time ago a part of my config disappeared. My guess was that I made changes manually in one `emacs` instance, and another `emacs` changed it automatically, when I added an agenda file. And this other instance of `emacs` had the config loaded, but stale, so a part of the config was lost. But I can't reproduce it now, so maybe I was wrong. Did that ever occur to you (losing changes owing to `emacs`)?

Comment: Are you talking about *editing* your init file?  When talking about Emacs configs and other elisp, the word `load` has a particular meaning which has nothing to do with editing the file.  It sounds like your question is about mishaps while editing?  (Emacs usually protects you against overwriting a newer version of the file, unless you tell it that you're certain you want to do that.)

Comment: Ah... ok, re-reading the question, I understand what you're asking now.  (And I don't have an answer offhand, sorry -- it's not a situation I usually need to worry about.)